# Open non-Xcode project in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Right now I'm working on a static website that uses markdown.  Rather than editing the files in SublimeText, I'd like to edit them in Xcode.  I can open the individual files in Xcode, but I want to open the entire static site directory and benefit from using the file navigator pane and other Xcode features.  Is this possible?

Reason: I've used Xcode for years and have come to really love the diffing tools, editor customizations, navigation, and keybindings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: It is about programming.  It's about markdown syntax and Xcode configuration.  Go ahead and go on a crusade to close all IDE configuration questions as off-topic... (including one of the most famous S.O. questions, 'How do I quit VIM?')

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out.

Create a new project in Xcode.  When prompted to choose a template, select `Cross-Platform`, then select `Empty`.  This will create an empty project.  You can then drag-drop your project directory into the empty project.  The git diff remains unchanged, ftw.