# how to add .xcodeproj to github repo

Tags: xcode, github, repository

I'm working on adding an app to the app store using Xcode from my github repo. Whenever I clone it through Xcode, it is unable to open - I'm assuming it is because there isn't a `.xcodeproj` file in my repo, but I'm not sure how to add it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right that it is because there is no `.xcodeproj` directory, etc., in your repo. I haven't found an easy way to have XCode create this for you. This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902978/3893444, might give you an approach.