# Why isn't my .xcodeproj file appearing in Github?

Tags: xcode, github

I've had a repository for my Xcode project for a while now, and have routinely been pushing updates to it. I am trying to transfer the project to a client's computer, but I can't because there's no .xcodeproj file in the repository. I've searched:

[no .xcodeproj file when downloading ZIP on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162190/no-xcodeproj-file-when-downloading-zip-on-github)
, but is making a new project really the best option? I'm not sure how to re-install of the Pod files that I'm using, and the answer linked to the question above is vague.
I tried deleting and adding new remotes but none of those have generated the .xcodeproj that I need. How would I go about adding a .xcodeproj file to Github?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think making a new project is the only good way to deal with Apple's expectation that you are working within their ecosystem. I haven't found an easy way to have XCode create this for you if it is missing. This answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902978/3893444, might give you an approach to resolving your issue.